# How to correct for MultiIndex.data deprecation

Tags: python, pandas, csv, deprecated, multi-index

I can't seem to find info on this deprecation. I am using a list of header locations to generate MultiIndex columns from a csv.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=[0,1], error_bad_lines=False)
```

If I then do anything with:

```
data.columns
```

I get the following FutureWarning:

```
<string>:1: FutureWarning: MultiIndex.data is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
```

How should I adjust my data importing code to access and work with the MultiIndex columns and deal with this deprecation (on which I can't seem to find documentation)?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using, `1.3.0` seems to complain about `error_bad_lines`,not MultIndex.data

Comment: An old one, it seems. I just did some reinstallations and it seems I missed an upgrade. That solved it quick, thanks.